# I have problem Concatenate with "&" and two value VBA excel

Tags: vba

I have problem with this code, it's showing me an error
, why is this wrong?

```
dim aData   as Variant
dim TBNumV  as Long
eRows       as Long
aData.value="433-333-"
TBNumV.value=0635
eRows=15
Range(eRows, 2).Value = aData.Value & TBNumV.Value
```

Comment: Remove the `.Value` calls as they are not valid and assign directly (`aData = "433-033-"`). Also remove them from the last line. Add a `Dim` before `eRows`. `TBNumV` should be a `String` not a `Long` as the leading zero needs to be retained (Phone numbers are strings not numbers). You want `Cells()` not `Range()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write something with a dot, you are referring to a method or property of an object. A Range is an object and has (among others) a property `Value` (is has also other properties like Font, Address, Interior...).

A simple variable like a `Long` is not an object in VBA, it has no properties, you simply write `TBNumV = 0635`.

A special case it the Variant, a Variant can be *anything*, depending on how you use it. You could assign an object to a variant variable (but you don't do in your code). You use it as a simple variable and want to assign a string to it: `aData = "433-333-"`. You could consider to declare `aData` as String, use Variant only if you really need to.

Then you have a syntax error declaring eRows, the `Dim`-statement is missing.

And your syntax for `Range` is wrong. Either write `Range("B" & eRows)` or you can use `Cells(eRows, 2)`.

```
Dim aData   As Variant
Dim TBNumV  As Long
Dim eRows       As Long
aData = "433-333-"
TBNumV = 635
eRows = 15
Cells(eRows, 2).Value = aData & TBNumV
```